# Django Django model “doesn't declare an explicit app_label” because of project's init.py file

Tags: python, django

I have a django 1.11 project with some rest_framework related apps. Writing tests for new app, I have suddenly gotten the issue

```
'RuntimeError: Model class core.myApp.models.query_record 
doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an 
application in INSTALLED_APPS'
```

I do have this listed in installed_apps, and in the end, the reason I have this issue is because I have an __init.py__ file in the top level of the project that loads some config for some related celery tasks.

I'm unaware why I haven't seen this issue in other app tests, as there is nothing particularly special about this app or it's model. But, this is causing all tests to fail for this app.

So, my question is, is there a way I can run these unit tests and ignore the projects top level __init.py__ ? Or maybe I should ask, is there a non-hacky way to do it?

the project level __init.py__:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .celeryapp import app as celery_app
```

All other app init.py files are empty.

Comment: Do you include the default config for each app in the app's __init__.py?

Comment: Please show the code in that `__init__.py`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I updated the question. However in talking with some other team members, this seems specific to my environment, which is strange as this is a fresh Vagrant and repo clone. I'm going to keep this question open until I determine the issue, and I will either update it or remove it if it's erroneous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, in the end this was simply because of how I was running tests

I was running tests like this

```
./manage.py test myApp --pattern=*.py
```

The pure wildcard was causing import issues. I should have done this:

```
./manage.py test myApp --pattern=prefix_*.py
```

D'oh.

Answer (score 0):

A problem might be, that `.celeryapp` is trying to import some models that aren't loaded yet.

You can try to add a AppConfig to core.myApp and load/import your celery app in it's `ready()` method. See the Django docs for more information [Django docs for more information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/applications/#application-configuration)